# Faceing error while trying to install a Managed Pakage on Spring 22 pre-release org

Tags: managed-package

I'm facing the following error:

> Layout: In field: excludeButtons, no such standard
> action:IsotopeSubscription

I've no idea whatsoever about the error. Can anyone help me out? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing you can do about this. You need to contact the vendor of the managed package and advise them of the issue on Spring '22 prerelease. Note however that this may or may not represent an actual issue in Spring '22; preview orgs occasionally contain unusual configurations that do not persist into production.

---

If you are working on this managed package, you'll need to remove the reference to `IsotopeSubscription` from your Page Layout metadata, which is likely something that was captured from a development org but never intended as part of your product *per se*.

Comment: Hello David! Thank you for your prompt response.
Actually I'm a part of the vendor team. I was wondering what I can do to fix the issue.

Comment: See my edit above.

Comment: Ow, thank you. I actually checked the metadata and found it on a layout.

Comment: However, do you have idea what it actually does? How it is going to effect after I remove it? Which part of Spring 22 release reflect it? Thank you.

Comment: Usually this occurs because a feature is retired in the platform or is no longer activated by default. I actually don't know what feature `IsotopeSubscription` is related to. There won't be any impact as such in Spring '22 because you're simply removing a button that is no longer available anyway.

Answer (score 2):

### Problem

My error looked like this:

```
MyCustomObject__c: No such standard button to exclude IsotopeSubscription
```

The error popped up recently for no apparent reason on a project that is several years old. With my particular DevOps setup, it was preventing me from pushing code changes. I'm guessing it was caused by platform updates made by Salesforce.

### Solution

I deleted all instances of the following:

```xml
<excludeButtons>IsotopeSubscription</excludeButtons>
```

(Found it in `.layout` files.)

And I deleted all instances of the following:

```xml
<excludedStandardButtons>IsotopeSubscription</excludedStandardButtons>
```

(Found it in `.object` files.)

That did it for me.

Comment: I have the same issue as you. I've removed all mention of IsotopeSubscription from all files but the error persists :(

Answer (score 1):

I had this error when creating 2GP package.

Fixed by upping to minor version instead of patch.

Previous version: 1.4.0

Failing version: 1.4.1

Working version: 1.5.0

Skipping ancestry check didn't make any difference.